# How to deal with searching piece of word in word with UISearchBar and UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, search, uisearchbar, words

I'm new with UISearchBar and i've got some code for searching words.

```
- (void)searchTableView
{
NSLog(@"Searching...");
NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;

NSMutableArray *tempSearch = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *item in items) {

    if ([[item objectForKey:@"en"] isEqualToString:searchText]) {
        NSLog(@"Found");

        [tempSearch addObject:item];
    }
}

searchArray = [tempSearch copy];
}
```

It works but problem is it works only for complete word (e.g. If in `textLabel` in `UITableViewCell` is text "something" and i type "something" in `UISearchBar` then i've got this row returned, but when i type "some" i've got rows when complete word is "some", "something" isn't showed). How can i search text correclty with my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NSPredicate` you can simplify your search a bit:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"en BEGINSWITH %@", searchText];
NSArray *tempSearch = [items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

If you want case-insensitive search, replace `BEGINSWITH` by `BEGINSWITH[c]`.

See [Using Predicates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html) in the "Predicate Programming Guide" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've got something but isn't correctly in 100%.

```
for (NSDictionary *item in items) {

    NSRange range = [[item objectForKey:@"en"] rangeOfString : searchText];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {

        NSLog(@"Found");

        [tempSearch addObject:item];
    }
}
```

When i type "e" i've got "some", "something", "else" - i think correctly will be when only "else" will be returned.

Ok i've got it.

```
    if (range.location != NSNotFound && range.location == 0) {
```